# How to create post thumbnail

Tags: php

I am working on the WordPress Twenty Ten theme, and I want to display post thumbnails.  I have followed the steps below:

- Added following code in functions.php file:

  ```
  if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
      add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
  }
  ```
- I have also defined post thumbnail size,

  ```
  set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
  ```
- And I configured the media settings from the admin panel of WordPress to not to crop image. but this is cropping the image.
- Using this in loop.php file,

  ```
  the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150);
  ```

I do not want to crop the image. How can I do this? Please help where I am wrong in my process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to retrieve thumbnail in size that you had set with `set_post_thumbnail_size()` then call `the_post_thumbnail()` without passing any arguments.

That will default to named `post-thumbnail` size that that `set_post_thumbnail_size()` actually creates.

Also crop for this will be determined by third argument in `set_post_thumbnail_size()` (defaults to `false`) and is not tied to media settings (those control entirely different sizes of image).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a typo, use

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150));
```

instead of

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150);
```

Another thing is, I've never used this in the loop.php only in functions.php

Comment: Thanks, But if i am using the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150)); in functions.php. It is displaying actual image size at lists of posts page.? But i need thumbnail size of 150*150.?

Comment: Ok, so you can try this: `if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
}` and if this does not work for you, maybe there's a conflict with another function.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to try:

1. Create a *new* custom image size: `add_image_size( 'my-custom-thumb', 150, 150 );` Play around with the dimensions, to see how WordPress reacts. There may be a collision, since there is already a 150x150 image size.
2. Regenerate your thumbnails, using the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) Plugin or the [Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) Plugin.
3. And, as @Rarst said: remove the array from the call to `the_post_thumbnail()`; either pass it no parameters, or pass it an `image-size-name` as an argument.

Comment: +1 for regenerating thumbnails. This step is non-obvious the first time one delves into all this.